# Google Analytics Event Trigger track in 2 Analytics accounts

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, event-tracking

Currently I have 2 Google Analytics accounts one used by me and another by a third party to view data. The problem is that only 1 account is recieving the correct event tracking:

```
 onclick="ga('send','event','Outbound Link', 'Clicked', 'http://URLFORTRACK')"
```

Both the accounts are initiated like this:

```
 <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)  {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new    Date();a=s.createElement(o),
     m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)   [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-1678855-1', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-1563345-1', 'auto', {'name': 'Marketo'});
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('Marketo.send', 'pageview');
```

My problem is that all the event tracking is being passed down to UA-177855-1 and I only have access to the other account UA-31861432-1. What can i do to make sure that tracking is either

a) being tracked in both accounts
b) possible to merge both accounts into one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using two trackers then you need to send the event hit for each tracker, for every event you want to have tracked.

Your code may need to be updated like this:

```
onclick="ga('send','event','Outbound Link', 'Clicked', 'http://URLFORTRACK'); ga('Marketo.send', 'event', .....);"
```

This way both properties receive the event hit.

I'm not sure what you mean by merging accounts, but in any case that likely isn't possible. You can't move data around properties in GA. But how you have it set up already, once you fix your inline tracking codes to send data to both properties, you will have essentially established properties that are collecting the same data.

Comment: Thank you so much  i didnt know i could add the second parameter in like that